# SKAction scaleBy: duration: SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I have a trouble trying to make one circle big and small using `[SKAction scaleBy: duration:]`

```
SKAction *scaleDown = [SKAction scaleBy:0.2 duration:1.8];  
SKAction *scaleUp= [scaleDown reversedAction];
SKAction *fullScale = [SKAction sequence:@[scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleDown, scaleUp]];
[_circleChanging runAction:fullScale];
```

What I get is the circle becoming so small that disappears and then doesn't come back. It has to become small and then come back to his original size doing it 2 times.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the circle continues to scale down until you can't see it any more, rather than stopping at a scale factor of 0.2, and scaling back up to its original size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
  SKAction *scaleDown = [SKAction scaleTo:0.2 duration:0.75];
       SKAction *scaleUp= [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.75];
       SKAction *fullScale = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleDown, scaleUp]]];
       [_circleChanging runAction:fullScale];
```

Comment: Thanks. It should have been obvious, but I was locked into believing `reversedAction` would actually do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Not all actions are reversible, and the reverse sometimes doesn't mean "go back to the original value".

If you [check the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/scaleBy%3aduration%3a), the reverse action of scaleBy is actually scaling to -0.2 in your case. Just create a new scale action instead of reversing.

Also try making a copy of the actions for the 2nd use:

```
SKAction *fullScale = [SKAction sequence:
                       @[scaleDown, scaleUp, [scaleDown copy], [scaleUp copy]]];
```

Comment: ok, I have changed: 

SKAction *scaleUp= [scaleDown reversedAction];

By:

SKAction *scaleUp= [SKAction scaleBy:3.0 duration:1.8];

and I still have the same main problem, the circle becomes as small that disappears.

Comment: check my update, perhaps this has to do with using the same actions multiple times in the sequence where they might need to be copies (more a guess than anything)